# What is wrong on this circuit? LDO Regulator TPS74401

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I'm testing a board that I designed. I'm measuring all the input pins from LDO Regulator TPS74401, and all of them are ok (3.2 V). With my schematic configuration, the output should be 1.1V but the assembler made a mistake with FB resistors and the values are completely different. Anyway, I don't understand why the measurement on the outputs are 0V. I suspect that the component is wrong because the component code doesn't seem TPS74401 (it shows other numbers and letters).

I attach a schematic and photo of the components.

Thank you so much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Page 32 of the [Fine Manual](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps74401.pdf) tells you that "12KA" is the expected package marking for a TPS74401RGR, so the assembler did place the correct part.

Comment: Thank you so much @brhans , I have searched on Google but it has showed nothing about that code. I didn't think about search on datasheet, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SS pin should not be grounded.
It should be left floating, or connected to a capacitor to ground.

I wouldn't be surprised if that would cause the regulator not to output any voltage, as the soft-start works by tracking the voltage on the SS pin as it is charged up at a controlled rate.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, thank you so much. My mistake, I replaced the capacitor by a wire.

Answer (score 2):

*Soft-start pin. A capacitor connected on this pin to ground sets the start-up time.
If this pin is left floating, the regulator output soft-start ramp time is typically 100 µs*

You didn't connect a capacitor to the SS pin. GND may cause a problem.

*Power-good (PG) is an open-drain, active-high output that indicates the status of VOUT.
When VOUT exceeds the PG trip threshold, the PG pin goes into a high-impedance state.
When VOUT is below this threshold, the pin is driven to a low-impedance state. Connect
a pullup resistor from 10 kΩ to 1 MΩ from this pin to a supply up to 5.5 V. The supply
can be higher than the input voltage.
Alternatively, the PG pin can be left floating if output monitoring is not necessary.*

You didn't pull up output to the PG pin. That may also cause a problem.

*If not used, EN can be connected to either IN or BIAS. If EN is connected to IN, connect EN as close as possible
to the largest capacitance on the input to prevent voltage droops on that line from triggering the enable circuit.*

I didn't understand why you put a resistor and capacitor for enable pin. You could either connect it directly or put a voltage divider to adjust.

Comment: "You didn't pull up output to the PG pin. That may also cause a problem." Not a problem for the regulator itself, as it is only an output. Also it is pulled up in the posted schematic, see R6.

Comment: As @Klas-Kenny says, PG shouldn't be the problem (is an output, not an input). The enable pin configuration is the same that Texas Instruments use on their design.